# push downloaded git repository to branch master

Tags: git, github

I downloaded a project of mine at GitHub (downloaded zip, not `git clone`).

I made some changes and now I want to commit and push it to origin master, how should I proceed? Always I do this, I find some workaround to push, so I'd like to know the correct way.

I guess I should do

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git remote add origin [repository_link]
git pull -u origin master
git push -u origin master
```

but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should "clone" instead of "download" if you'd like to push to the same repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay are you suggesting that I clone the repo, overwritte the original content with my already modified content and commit it? would it work?

Comment: anyway, it's obvious that I should have cloned from the beginning, but for this question, I didn't. I wasn't expecting to change the project but I did and I forgot it wasn't cloned

Comment: Make a clone and then merge the changes in the downloaded repository to the cloned one with a tool like BeyondCompare. Technically the solution in your question is doable, but it would create a weird history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to push back to a repository, you should `clone` it instead of `downloading` it.

That being said, I understand the issue here is that you downloaded it and didn't realize that when you made the changes.

I would suggest to clone the project into a different folder.
Then you can replace all files from the old downloaded folder to the new cloned folder.

Do a `git status` and `git diff` to make sure everything looks good.

Now you can `git push origin master`